# How to differentiate between binary and hexadecimal values

Tags: javascript, binary, hex

Let's say that I needed the user to enter a binary or hexadecimal value and the program would take it from there. Is there a way to differentiate whether the value they entered is binary or hexadecimal?

I thought I had it figured out by checking if the string contained letters or numbers above 1 but what about in the case of 101101 or other similar hex inputs? Is it even possible to know without any other context?

For the sake of including failed attempts I tried the following to check if the string contained letters which hexadecimal values could:

```
if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(input)))
```

but other than it not solving the above problem (since hex values don't always have letters), it also fails because it still returns true when letters are mixed into the input as it still parses an integer one way or another.

Comment: How could it be possible when, as you note, some values could be either binary or hex and you would have no idea of user intent just by looking at the string?

Comment: @stephen.vakil to add to that, the same number could be decimal or oct and it would still be valid. You cannot tell that IRL if somebody wrote it on a piece of paper without asking them, so I can't really see how you'd be able to do it programmatically. I don't think the mind-read module is ready for beta testing yet.

Comment: @stephen.vakil I kind of knew the answer to this and figured as such but I wanted to get the opinion of more experienced developers as I could not find much else by google searching just converters or Regexp tests that failed on the value I provided above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it even possible to know without any other context?

No, it's not. Programming languages often allow number literals in various numeral systems but they have to be marked accordingly. In JavaScript:

- No prefix: decimal. Example: `12345`
- `0b` prefix: binary. Example: `0b10101`
- `0o` prefix: octal. Example: `0o123`
- `0x` prefix: hexadecimal. Example: `0x12345`

You could require the same notation for the input, or you provide another control that allows the user to choose the system (you could still internal prefix the input correctly).

---

For completeness, here is a function that would convert any of these inputs to numbers:

```js
const radixTable = {
  '0b': 2,
  '0o': 8,
  '0x': 16,
};

function convert(str) {
  let radix = 10;
  if (radixTable.hasOwnProperty(str.slice(0, 2))) {
      radix = radixTable[str.slice(0,2)];
      str = str.slice(2);
  }
  return parseInt(str, radix);
}

['12', '0b1100', '0o14', '0xC'].forEach(
  str => console.log(`${str}:`, convert(str))
);
```

Comment: If it's a normal person inputting it, it's probably more user friendly to have a text input and a radio button or a dropdown to choose the type of value. Still, doesn't change the fact that you need the user to be explicit with their intention

Comment: Hm this is what I thought but I wanted to confirm it with more experienced developers. I wanted to keep it as simple as possible for the user and have them input the minimum amount of information (just the string) but it looks like it will require more than that. Thank you for the informative answer.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy: If the target audience knows what binary, octal and hex numbers are, then they might also know about the prefix already.

Comment: @FelixKling They might or might not (know about the prefixes) but the prefixes are definitely the best route to go and it will just require a little bit more documentation on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of JavaScript having a lot of advanced math capabilities built in. If it was oriented toward that end, it would probably have more numeric variable types to give you larger numbers like a double or long. You might want to create an object that would have a property to set whether the number in the object is hex or decimal, and then the value.

```
let numberObj = {
    numberSystem: 'decimal',
    value: '4505'
}
```